# Subdomain on different ip

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain, digital-ocean, cloudflare

Hello guys, i trying to create a new subdomain in my CloudFlare account but didn't work.

The root domain (mysite.com) is linked to heroku app, but i would like to link the subdomain (sub.mysite.com) to other server with different IP. I used 'A' record for this, but didn't work. My config is below. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Does using SSL in the root domain can be the problem?

[image]

.

Comment: Your A record looks fine. How did you determine it did not work?

Comment: I try to connect to a specific port or access the server's dashboard like 'abc.mysite.com:8083'. The rule for always use HTTP is enable in cloudflare 'mysite.com/*' @DusanBajic

Comment: That tests much more than DNS. Go to https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ and test if your subdoman resolves to correct IP. If it does, then investigate your server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dusan Basic noted, your DNS looks to be correct. Try taking traffic to the subdomain off Cloudflare by clicking the orange load for this record.